# Windows Fax server cannot use CallerID - how to enable this

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, fax

Using Windows server 2008's built-in Fax Server, seems to work fine, but it does not seem to access the CallerID at all. The Fax server can auto send an email with the fax and includes a field "CallerID" that is always blank. My modem supports caller-id, my phone line has caller-id service. I used HyperTerminal to connect to the fax-modem and watched it send the caller-id correctly. I added the AT+VCID=1 command to the modem device initialization string in control panel. Still no CallerID in the email.

Has anyone got this to work? any ideas?

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 1):

According to the MS support forum, the modem driver must support CallerID for it to work.(and of course, you must have CallerID service on your phone line) I tried 3 different modems (US robotics, and 2 others) that support callerID. They all needed an Init string in the Modem driver to enable it (AT+VCID=1). They all worked via commands entered into HyperTerminal. None worked with CallerID when used with the Microsoft Fax Server program.

I ended up buying VentaFax for $100- which worked the first time, runs as a service and seems nicer overall. I really wanted to use the 'free' Fax server but does not get good support.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I done to have Windows 2008 Server Fax Server to work with my Caller ID on a USR Courier V Everything modem.

With Hyper Terminal or Putty, enter the following commands:

ATS0=2 (Set auto answer to 2 rings)
AT#CID=2 (Enable Caller ID with unformatted output)
AT&W (Save the settings)

With Microsoft Fax Service Manager, set the Automatic Answer, Rings before answering to 2.

This did for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. After enabling Caller ID (e.g. AT#CID=1 or AT#VCID=1 and getting an OK response)

When you are connected to the modem via Putty and you call your modem, does it show the caller ID there? but prefixes it with DDN? e.g. "DDN 5555555555"

I think Windows Fax and Scan/Fax Server is looking for NMBR then the Caller ID # but since it can't find it, it just comes up blank.

I knew I had caller id on my line active and my modem supported it but it always showed up as DDN. run regedit as administrator and find "NMBR=" and change it to "DDN=" Also search for "NMBR =" and change it to "DDN =" if you find it.

Reboot and it should work.

I am in Canada by the way. Using a USR 5637 usb modem. Windows Server 2012 R2.